# Understanding JFileChooser behaviour

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am trying to open a `JFileChooser` dialog to let the user decide his wish-directory for following operations.

Following is my current code:

```
JFileChooser chooser;
if(pref.get("LAST_PATH", "") != null){
    chooser = new JFileChooser(pref.get("LAST_PATH", ""));
} else{
    chooser = new JFileChooser(home_dir);
}
//chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
int retVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
```

home_dir is a static String pointing to the users Download-directory.

The behaviour I do not understand:

```
home_dir = C:/Users/Scy/Downloads
```

Press OK without selecting any file(Or directory)

```
Output: C:/Users/Scy
```

---

```
home_dir = C:/Users/Scy/Downloads
```

Select any file within Downloads

```
Output: C:/Users/Scy/Downloads
```

Why do I not get the full-path(`C:/Users/Scy/Downloads`) as output when not selecting anything and just pressing OK? (With `DIRECTORIES_ONLY` activated, can't press OK without selecting anything without `DIRECTORIES_ONLY`)

Edit: I just noticed that when I just press the Cancel button without selecting anything the output is indeed what I expect, `C:/Users/Scy/Downloads`.

Based on an answer on this post I tried the following:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(home_dir)); //home_dir = "C:/Users/Scy/Downloads"
```

The result was exactly the same as above. Pressing the Cancel button results in the full path output, while pressing OK/Accept results in `C:/Users/Scy`.

Comment: "Select any file within Downloads Output: C:/Users/Scy/Downloads" This is where I am confused by your question. When you select a **file** in a directory, `getParentDirectory()` should return the name of said directory. What else do you expect? More importantly, what behavior do you **want**?

Comment: Where do I use `getParentDirectory()`? `getCurrentDirectory()` returns the parent directory of any given file I put into it. So selecting a directory or more specifically `C:/Users/Scy/Downloads` results in `C:/Users/Scy` while it should be `C:/Users/Scy/Downloads`, because that is the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the 'selected file'(or directory) is in the 'current directory' (which you are retrieving atm.)?

If you want the current selected file, `chooser.getSelectedFile()` is what you are looking for. Keep in mind that when switching to DirectoryOnly mode this method will return a directory (e.g. a File instance representing a directory).

The method `chooser.getCurrentDirectory()` will return the parent directory of the current selected file which explains the unexpected results. (`getSelectedFile.getParentFile()` will most likely return the same file)

If you are trying to retrieve the parentDirectory, you set the starting directory incorrect. Notice how you pass in the first constructor a selected File? This means in the second constructor the 'home_dir' will be the selected File. If you only want to set 'home_dir' as starting directory, you should use the no-args constructor and call  `chooser.setCurrentDirector(new File(home_dir))` instead. Here is a snippit of what your code could look like:

```
JFileChooser chooser;
if(pref.get("LAST_PATH", "") != null){
    // set last SELECTED file/directory path.
    chooser = new JFileChooser(pref.get("LAST_PATH", ""));
 } else{
     // set currentDirectory,  but dont select anything yet.
     chooser = new JFileChooser();
     chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(home_dir));
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @Meik Vtune Edited the question, might be a bit clearer now

Comment: As said right at the start, the goal is to get the current directory and save that. So if the user is in a directory like `E:/Some/Dirs/`, the goal is to get exactly that path, not `E:/Some`.

Comment: I think something might be confusing here, a java `File` object can represent both a fild and a directory. So again, if you want to select a working directory (which you setup the chooser for by setting directoryOnl) you need `getSelectedFile()` which returns the current selected DIRECTORY. When you want the parent directory of a selected file, the getter is correct, though setting the starting directory is incorrect.(and maybe switch ti file selection instead?)

Comment: I just noticed that you might think home_dir is a File, it is indeed a String. `setCurrentDirectory` expects a File.

Comment: I tried what you said and it still results in exactly the same output, where pressing cancel is the right output while pressing ok does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121997/discussion-between-meik-vtune-and-n247s).

Answer (score 1):

[`getCurrentDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getCurrentDirectory()) returns a **directory** name, not a file name. If the user selects a file, this method returns the name of the directory which contains that file. If you want the name of the file which was selected, you should use [`getSelectedFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()). If you haven't yet, you should read [this Oracle tutorial on file choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: You should read the first sentence, my goal is NOT to get the selected file, but to get the currentDirectory, which is not working as expected.

Comment: @MeikVtune Please clarify. What are you expecting that is different than what occurs? It might help if you give a **specific** example with made up file and directory names.

Comment: The question has been answered by @n247s in the chat, `getCurrentDirectory()` seems to use `selectedFile.parentFile()`, which always results in it "cutting off" the last part, which is not what I was expecting, and it also is not explained anywhere in the JavaDocs.